# I'm stuck for 2 days with probably an obvious thing - PHP + Laravel image update

Tags: php, laravel, image, upload

I started creating an e-commerce platform and I'm stuck with a problem I can't solve for 2 days.. It's probably something obvious but I just can't find the solution for this. Could you help me with this, please? I get this error:

> Missing required parameters for [Route: images.update] [URI: dashboard/images/{image}]. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce\ecommerce\resources\views\website\admin\product_image\update.blade.php)

**update.blade.php**

```
@extends('website.admin.layouts.main')
@section('content')

<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 ">
  <div class="x_panel">
    <div class="x_title">
      <h2>Zaktualizuj obraz</h2>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="x_content">
      <br />

      <form id="updateimage-form" data-parsley-validate="" class="form-horizontal form-label-left" novalidate="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="{{route('images.update', $productImage->id)}}">

        @csrf
        @method('PUT')

        <div class="item form-group">

          <label class="col-form-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 label-align" for="first-name">Produkt<span class="required">*</span></label>

          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 ">
            <select class="form-control" name="product_id">

              @foreach ($product as $prodcat)

                <option value="{{$prodcat -> id}}" name="product_id">{{ $prodcat -> product_name }}</option>

              @endforeach

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="ln_solid"></div>

        <div class="item form-group">
          <label class="col-form-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 label-align" for="first-name">Nazwa obrazu<span class="required">*</span></label>
          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 ">
            <input type="text" id="img_title" name="img_title" placeholder="Image Title" value="{{ $productImage -> image_name }}" required="required" class="form-control ">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item form-group">
          <label class="col-form-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 label-align" for="first-name">Wgraj obraz<span class="required">*</span></label>
          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 ">
            <input type="file" name="img" id="img" onchange="fileSelected();"/>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item form-group">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 offset-md-3">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="reset">Wyczyść</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Zaktualizuj obraz</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

@endsection
```

**models\ProductImage.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ProductImage extends Model
{
  protected $fillable = [
    'product_id',
    'image_name',
    'image',
    'slug',
    'status'
  ];

  public function product()
  {
    return $this -> belongsTo('App\Models\models\Product');
  }
}
```

**ProductImageController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\models\Product;
use App\Models\models\ProductImage;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class ProductImageController extends Controller
{
  public function index()
  {
    $productImage = ProductImage::all();
    return view('website.admin.product_image.index', compact('productImage'));
  }

  public function create()
  {
    $product = Product::all();
    return view('website.admin.product_image.create', compact('product'));
  }

  public function store(Request $request)
  {
    $slug = Str::slug($request->image_name, '-');

    $image = time().'.'.$request->image->extension();
    $request->image->move(public_path('images'), $image);

    ProductImage::create([
      'image_name'=>$request->image_name,
      'image'=>$image,
      'product_id'=>$request->product_id,
      'slug'=>$slug,
    ]);

    return redirect()->route('images.index');

    }

    public function show(ProductImage $ProductImage)
    {
      //
    }

    public function edit(ProductImage $productImage)
    {
      $product = Product::all();
      return view('website.admin.product_image.update',compact('productImage','product'));
    }

    public function update(Request $request, ProductImage $productImage)
    {
      $slug=Str::slug($request->image_name,'-');

      if($request->image)
      {
        $image = time() .'.'. $request -> image -> extension();
        $request->image->move(public_path('images'), $image);
      }
      else
      {
        $image=$productImage->image;
      }

      $productImage->update([
        'image_name'=>$request->image_name,
        'image'=>$image,
        'product_id'=>$request->product_id,
        'slug'=>$slug,
      ]);

      return redirect()->route('images.index');
    }

    public function destroy(productImage $productImage)
    {
      $productImage->delete();
      return redirect()->route('images.index');
    }
}
```

**routes/web.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('website.shop.layouts.main');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');

Route::get('/dashboard', [App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController::class, 'index'])->name('dashboard.index');

Route::resource('/dashboard/categories', 'App\Http\Controllers\ProductCategoryController');
Route::resource('/dashboard/product', 'App\Http\Controllers\ProductController');
Route::resource('/dashboard/images', 'App\Http\Controllers\ProductImageController');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this, the problem was with "images" name in route. I changed it to something else everywhere and it works now.

Answer (score 1):

**update.blade.php**

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('images.update', $productImage->id)}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    @csrf
    @method('PUT')
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="filename">Select your Image</label>
        <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Update</button>
    </div>

</form>
```

**ProductImageController.php**

```
<?php

  namespace App\Http\Controllers;

  use App\Models\models\ProductImage;;
  use Illuminate\Http\Request;


  class DocumentController extends Controller
  {
      public function update(Request $request, $productId){
           $product = ProductImage::findOrFail($productId);
           if($request->hasfile('image'))
           {
             $file = $request->file('image');
             $name=$file->getClientOriginalName();
             $file->move(public_path().'/uploads/ProductImages/', $name);
             $file = $name;
             $product->image = $file;
       
           }
           $product->save();
           return redirect()->back();    
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`action="{{route('images.update', $productImage->id)}}"` is incorrect way of calling `route()` helper function. Consider the following snippet;

```
action="{{route('images.update', [
    'image' => $productImage->id
])}}"
```

For more details about `route()` helper, see this link; https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-route

Comment: Still doesn't work for me, with updating product or category I had no problem with that, but only with updating image

Comment: Apply this answer onto `update.blade.php` file. And see what kind of error is happening.

Comment: Try `php artisan route:list` and give me the result please.

Comment: DELETE    | dashboard/images/{image}             | images.destroy
 | App\Http\Controllers\ProductImageController@destroy                    | web
       |
PUT|PATCH | dashboard/images/{image}             | images.update
 | App\Http\Controllers\ProductImageController@update                     | web
       |
GET|HEAD  | dashboard/images/{image}             | images.show
 | App\Http\Controllers\ProductImageController@show                       | web
       |
GET|HEAD  | dashboard/images/{image}/edit        | images.edit
 | App\Http\Controllers\ProductImageController@edit

Comment: Nothing changed

Comment: Can I come to your workspace via remote control? It seems like needing runtime debugging.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have Model Binding happening here you have Dependency Injection happening instead. For Implicit Route Model Binding to take place you have to match the type hinted parameter of your method to the name of the route parameter. In your case the route parameter is named `image`, not `productImage`. So you are getting an empty new instance of `ProductImage` instead of the replacement for the Route Model Binding.

Change your controller's parameter to match the route parameter:

```
                                   vvvvv
public function edit(ProductImage $image)
```

You would need to change this in all the methods you want the Implicit Binding for, unless you want to override the parameter used in the route.

```
                                                       vvvvv
public function update(Request $request, ProductImage $image)
```

At the moment you are passing an empty model to your view which is then trying to use it's "id" to generate a route, but "id" is `null` and route parameters can no to `null`.